# Bug when I want to view Badge information

Tags: bug, badges, profile-page

I don't know whether it is just me or anyone happen to see this too. When I open a badge to select any badge to see the information, its like bug to bottom. I cannot scroll until the bottom.
[image]

Comment: This doesn't happen to me, have you tried scrolling outside the window to try pull the background down? For me the entire window fits on the screen, how big is your monitor, and whats your resolution?

Comment: @Twyxz still the same. I try scrolling outside windows but nothing happened. It's like when I scroll inside badge it reached the bottom but the badge windows seems stuck on the bottom.  My Laptop screen is 15.6'. My resolution is 1366 x 768.

Comment: Yeah, that dialog doesn't play nice with smaller screen resolutions. The issue is on our radar, but I don't have an ETA for a fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This definitely looks like a screen resolution issue, and not so much a bug. I tried adjusting my browser window so that it was small enough to cut off the badge window, and I saw the same effect as you; once you have the badge list open, you cannot scroll the main page.

Two solutions that worked for me:

- Close the badge window, scroll the main page down just a bit, and then re-open the badges. The badge window should have moved slightly with the rest of the background.
- Zoom out on your browser (`Ctrl`+`scroll`) until the whole badge window is visible. This also makes all of the text smaller, so it may not be the most desirable solution.

Comment: Yeah, I try both solution and its okay now. Its screen issue then.